# payment module not working in magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1, amazon-pay

I have a magento store, and it's payment module is not working. I can add my shipping method, but after submitting shipping method,

> it won't proceed to payment mode,

I have enabled cash on delivery. and

> I have an amazon payment extension also. When I checked in console,
>   there shows some error, That is client ID is invalid in amazon, But
>   the extension is disabled

, still it causing problem, i think so,

But

> Checkout with Multiple Addresses is working without any problem.

Can any one please help me, this is my website link [please check](http://kingporchswings.com/index.php/swing-types/stained.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the client ID that was given to you by wizard. I ran into the same problem.

1. Go to your Amazon SellerCenter Account.
2. Then from Top right drop-down list select Login with Amazon.
3. From right side select the Application you want the information for.
4. Under Web Settings take the Client ID.

Comment: Thanks Bro, This solved my issue already. Any way Thanks and appreciation.. :)